# Remove linebreaks from a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data and code below how can I remove all the line breaks from the data?

Data:

```
  ID            a        
  0BX-164463    abc \n def
  0BX-164463    hijk \n lmnop
  0BX-164464    qrst \n uvwxyz
  0BX-164464    12345 \n abcdefg \n gravy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
gsub("\\n", "", "abc \n def")
#[1] "abc  def"
```

If you want to remove the spaces as well:

```r
gsub("\\n|\\s", "", "abc \n def")
#[1] "abcdef"
```

Comment: If there are multiple columns, then I have to specify all of them?

Comment: No, you can use e.g. `across` in `dplyr`, or `sapply` in base R

Comment: So `df %>% across(gsub("\\n", "")` ?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(across(your_columns, ~ gsub("\\n", "", .x)))`

Comment: Thank you, `your_columns` = `type all columns one by one`? and what is `.x` for?

Comment: Check `?across`, you can use `tidy-select` functions to select your columns.

Answer (score 1):

Other option with `str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(data$a, "\n", "")
```

or also with the removal of spaces:

```
str_replace_all(data$a, "\n| ", "")
```